# Git patch mode quirk: hunk does not apply after a split

Tags: git

I found a weird quirk in git, and I wan't to know what mechanism stands behind what I'm seeing.

Let's say I have a repository with an already committed file `test`, which has the following contents:

```
A
B

C
D
```

Now, I make some changes to it:

```
1
A

C
2
D
```

(I removed `B`, added a `1` and a `2`)

If I now try to add only the `2` line via `git add -p`, by first splitting the changes, discarding the first two and applying the `2` (by pressing `y`), everything goes as expected. But if I try to add it by editing it (pressing `e`), even if I didn't change anything about it and just exit the editor, git will not want to apply the hunk.

Why is that?

Comment: It's pretty clearly a bug. The perl script that implements interactive add runs `git apply --check` on the piece, and `git apply --check` is failing. It's not clear why `git apply --check` fails, though.

Comment: It has been already talked about in the past http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Git-add-p-Your-edited-hunk-does-not-apply-Edit-again-td7628700.html. I can reproduce with `git version 2.15.1.433.g936d1b9`.

Comment: I think that the problem is well-know and still not fixed as `t3701-add-interactive.sh` testcase still fails but the comment says `# TODO known breakage`.